# can you make Keyboard events differ on different pages?

Tags: actionscript-3, keyboard, frame, addeventlistener, stage

Hey is there a way to have certain keys do one thing on one page and then different on another, as i use

But then on next frame i cant use space bar again to do another task?
Any help would be appreciated

```
stop();
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, myKeyDownn);
function myKeyDownn(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
    if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.SPACE){
        gotoAndPlay("welcome");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just remove the listener before you leave the frame.

```
stop();
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, myKeyDownn);
function myKeyDownn(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
    if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.SPACE){
        stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, myKeyDownn);
        gotoAndPlay("welcome");
    }
}
```

in the frame "welcome" add the same code again and just change the `gotoAndPlay()` part.

```
stop();
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, myKeyDownn);
function myKeyDownn(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
    if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.SPACE){
        stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, myKeyDownn);
        gotoAndPlay("a different frame");
    }
}
```

Comment: An [anonymous user comments](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2946312): you might need `stage.focus = stage;` after the `stop();`.